Tensorflowjs keras model node weights aren't recognized
I'm facing an error when calling a pre-trained keras model in javascript for a simple web app on Heroku.
https://digit-predictor-6ba58c0cd85a.herokuapp.com

Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Corrupted configuration, expected array for nodeData: [object Object]

The issue is seen consistently across Heroku and the live server.
The model's information is contained in model.json and its node weights are contained in  group1-shard1of1.bin. I believe all the files are deposited their correct places, and correctly referenced.
I'm expecting the model to load, but the model won't load because of the error.
I don't know if it's because of the ".bin" format, which is the only option when using tensorflowjs_converter. To troubleshoot, I tried using someone else's model that was accompanied by a corresponding COM Executable for DOS type file. That version worked. However, I need to use my own model architecture and node weights for my project.
I googled [object Object] but all I'm seeing is that it's a string version of an object instance.

This is not a solution but a workaround. The error is caused by tfjs not able to build a model from a functional definition, if your model has a sequential architecture rewrite it using keras sequential api and this should do the trick.
